# add_action with variable as a part of the $tag string

Tags: custom-taxonomy, actions

I am trying to create meta fields to multiple custom taxonomy terms. I put the complete code inside a foreach but nothing is working.

```
$taxs = get_object_taxonomies( 'product' );

foreach($taxs as $terms){  
    add_action( "{$terms}_add_form_fields", '___add_form_field_term_meta_text' );
```

Is it possible to use the `$terms` variable like that?

Comment: Yes. It is possible. If it's not working then the issue is probably with your `___add_form_field_term_meta_text` function. What does that look like?

Comment: the code was fine coz I t worked without the variable. The problem apparently is Im using get_object_taxonomies from a plugin file, which returns an empty array. For now I put in the tax names manually into an array. Do you know how I can get the get_object_taxonomies to work in the plugin files?

Comment: You need to make sure the code runs after the taxonomies are registered. This normally happens on `init`.

Answer (score -1):

You can try this :

```
add_action( $terms.'_add_form_fields', '___add_form_field_term_meta_text' );
```

Comment: This works also, but the prob was me using get_object_taxonomies in a plugin file. Which returns an empty array. Know how to get that working?